# ¿Se puede añadir código dentro de un echo?

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente pregunta: Si hago un echo de una variable, y esta contiene cualquier tipo de código (html, php, javascript, etc) ¿Será ejecutado o solo se verá en forma de texto?

Tengo esta duda porque quiero asegurarme de que la gente no pueda añadir código en los formularios, que luego van a ser mostrados en una página.

Y bueno, estoy convencido de que se puede hacer con algunos como JavaScript, entonces, ¿Cuál sería la solución para que no se ejecute el código?

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de un `echo` puedes sin problema enviar código `html` o `javascript` ahora bien tus campos de formularios deberían pasar por un filtro antes de proceder a ejecutar cualquier acción con los datos de estos, considera que todos tus usuarios son hackers, siempre.

Que podrías hacer ?

**Validacion con HTML de tus Inputs**

HTML ha evolucionado bastante y una de estas evoluciones es la validacion de los campos de entrada de formularios como por ejemplo un campo numérico

```
<input type="number">
```

o

```
<input type="email" required>
```

Ambos campos requieren una entrada valida como indica el atributo `type` puedes auxiliarte de este tipo de validación, aunque hago énfasis en que no es definitivo.

> Nota: El atributo `required` forza al usuario a rellenar este dato.

Tambien existe el atributo `pattern`le permite ejecutar validaciones de expresiones regulares contra valores de entrada. Si, por ejemplo, requiere que las contraseñas contengan al menos 1 carácter en mayúscula, 1 carácter en minúscula y 1 número, el navegador puede validarlo para ti.

```
<input type="password" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$" required>
```

Puedes encontrar mucha mas info en el siguiente enlace : [Validaciones con HTML](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-1-constraint-validation-html/)

**JavaScript**

Con javascript existen un montón de soluciones, desde utilizar `jquery` y sus librerías para validación de formularios o utilizar `vanilla javascript` y su poderosa `API`, esta parte es bastante amplia así que te invito a entrar al siguiente enlace y verlo por ti mismo:
[Validaciones con Javascript](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-2-constraint-validation-api-javascript/)

De todos modos te dejo un ejemplo muy basico;

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Debe colocar un nombre");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>Deja el nombre vacio y pulsa <strong>submit</strong></div>
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Nombre: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

Bueno, ya entramos en un terreno que no podemos jamas en la vida olvidar y es la validación en el `backend` es de suma importancia no dejar toda las validaciones solo al navegador, digase `HTML` y `Javascript`.

Lo bueno de esto es que contamos con muchas funciones y utilidades del lado de nuestro servidor, como por ejemplo:

**stripslashes** Quita las barras de un string con comillas escapadas.

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Salida: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

o un caso mas apegado a tu pregunta, si un usuario ingresa codigo javascript en un input que se te paso validar;

**strip_tags** Retira las etiquetas HTML y PHP de un string.

```
?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Permite <p> y <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Mas sobre esto en la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

**Mi conclusión**

Hay muchas formas de validar y de evitar que tus usuarios inyecten código de cualquier tipo pero esto quedaría a tu consideración cuales utilizar y cuales te convienen, los que he planteado no son definitivos y son podrían contener sus fallos y contras pero opino que dejar los inputs sin validar del lado del cliente no crea una buena experiencia.

Answer (score 1):

> `echo` no de debe preocupar para ataques de inyección de código en el
>   lado del servidor

Por otro lado, si lo que te preocupa es la inyección de código, puedes utilizar la función `strip_tags` para tratar de eliminar las etiquetas html y php de una cadena de texto.

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

Puedes ver la documentación completa en [php.net](http://php.net/strip%20tags)