# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo este error en mi archivo settings.php

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\settings.php on line 74
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\settings.php on line 74

en la linea 74 tengo esto

```
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($data);
  if($statement->execute($data))
  {
   $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Profile Updated</div>';
  }
```

trate de corregirlo pero no encuentro una solución alguien tiene alguna idea de como arreglar estos errores? 
y si tienen alguna idea de como mejorar el código me ayudaría mucho

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=;charset=utf8',"","");
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if(!isset($id))
{
 header('location:/');
}

$message = '';

if(isset($_POST['edit_profile']))
{
 $file_name = '';
 if(isset($_POST['profile_image']))
 {
  $file_name = $_POST['profile_image'];
 }

 if($_FILES['profile_image']['name'] != '')
 {
  if($file_name != '')
  {
   unlink('img/avatar/'.$file_name);
  }
  $image_name = explode(".", $_FILES['profile_image']['name']);
  $extension = end($image_name);
  $temporary_location = $_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_name = rand() . '.' . strtolower($extension);
  $location = 'img/avatar/' . $file_name;
  move_uploaded_file($temporary_location, $location);
 }
 $check_query = "
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = :username AND id != $id
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($check_query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':username'  =>  trim($_POST["username"]),
  )
 );
 $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
 if($total_row > 0)
 {
  $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Username Already Exists</div>';
 }
 else
 {
  $data = [
   ':username'   => $_POST["username"],
   ':profile_image' => $file_name,
   ':bio'    => $_POST["bio"]
  ];
  if($_POST['password'] != '')
  {
   $data = [
    ':password'  => hash('sha512', $_POST["password"])
   ];
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET usuario=:username,pasword=:password,tipo='user',avatar=:profile_image,bio=:bio,bloqueado='0',verify='0' WHERE id = $id
   ";
  }
  else
  {
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET usuario=:username,pasword=:password,tipo='user',avatar=:profile_image,bio=:bio,bloqueado='0',verify='0' WHERE id = $id
   ";
  }

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($data);
  if($statement->execute($data))
  {
   $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Profile Updated</div>';
  }
 }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">Edit Profile</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <?php
       foreach($result as $row)
       {
        echo $message;
       ?>
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Username</label>
         <input type="text" name="username" id="username" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$" required class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row["usuario"];?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Profile Image</label>
         <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="profile_image" accept="image/*" />
         <?php
         if($row["avatar"] != '')
         {
          echo '<img src="img/avatar/'.$row["avatar"].'" class="img-thumbnail" width="150" />';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="profile_image" value="'.$row["avatar"].'" />';
         }
         ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Short Bio</label>
         <textarea name="bio" id="bio" class="form-control"><?php echo $row["bio"]; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" name="edit_profile" id="edit_profile" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>
       </form>
       <?php
       }
       ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta aqui;

```php
   $query = "
   UPDATE user SET usuario=:username,pasword=:password,tipo='user',avatar=:profile_image,bio=:bio,bloqueado='0',verify='0' WHERE id = $id
   ";
  }

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($data);
```

En tu consulta pasas `:username, :password , :profile_image, :bio` pero en tu `$data` array solo pasas;

```php
  $data = [
   ':username'   => $_POST["username"],
   ':profile_image' => $file_name,
   ':bio'    => $_POST["bio"]
  ];
```

Te falta pasar el `password`. La cantidad de marcadores o parametros que pases en tu consulta deben ser igual a la cantidad que le pasas en tu array en el metodo `execute`

La solucion seria agregar en tu `$data` array el parametro;

```php
 $data = [
   ':username'   => $_POST["username"],
   ':password' =>$_POST["password"],
   ':profile_image' => $file_name,
   ':bio'    => $_POST["bio"]
  ];
```

NOTA: Claramente no deberías estar pasando parámetros a tu base de datos sin antes depurar los, realizar esto directamente desde el array `$_POST` no es para nada seguro.

Te recomiendo leer un poco en este enlace [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202460/se-puede-a%c3%b1adir-c%c3%b3digo-dentro-de-un-echo/202483#202483](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202460/se-puede-a%C3%B1adir-c%C3%B3digo-dentro-de-un-echo/202483#202483)